# El JS que ejecuto con selenium no funciona igual que en la consola

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

estoy trabajando con un bot de selenium y python, ocupo hacer un `document.querySelector("table[class='grid-table sessions']").scrollIntoView();` para mostrar un elemento en la pantalla, funciona cuando lo pongo en la consola de la pagina, pero cuando ejecuto el codigo me sale esto `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null`

El codigo exato es:

`self.driver.execute_script('''document.querySelector("table[class='grid-table sessions']").scrollIntoView();''')`

La pagina es mega.nz (https://mega.nz/fm/account/security)

por que?

Comment: podrías mostrar como lo ejecutas ?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta @lucas damian

Comment: si quieres mostrar el elemento, tienes que agregarle `return` antes del `document.query....`